Losing all catalogs from `data` of the `data_dir` directory
We met an unpleasant issue with GeoServer. During its runtime, all catalogs of the 'data', including raster images and shape files, were removed. We checked about this issue in logfiles but this file wasn't saved.
So what could be the reason for this issue? Is it a system problem, or could GeoServer remove catalogs by itself?

were you doing an upgrade at the time? You shouldn't really store your data directory within the GeoServer install
